# How to order by nested objects fields?

Tags: angularjs, django, django-rest-framework

I have some classes

```
class MarketProduct(models.Model, ObjectMarket):
    _state_class = 'MarketProductState'

    uuid = models.UUIDField(u'Код',
                        default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(u'Название',
                        max_length=255, db_index=True)
class MarketItem(models.Model, ObjectMarket):
    _state_class = 'MarketItemState'

    STOCK, AUCTION = 1, 2
    ITEM_CHOICES = (
        (STOCK, u'Сток'),
        (AUCTION, u'Аукцион'),
    )

    product = models.ForeignKey(MarketProduct)
    start_at = models.DateTimeField(u'Начало продажи')
```

I want to get MarketItemViewSet and use

```
filter_backends = (filters.OrderingFilter,`)
```

I send request with filed `orderby` by angular.
If I send `orderby = start_at`, all are good, but I want to send
`orderby = product.id`, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using django-rest-framework you have to use `ordering_fields` as you can see from the documentation [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#orderingfilter).Hope it helps example:

```
class UserListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.OrderingFilter,)
    ordering_fields = ('username', 'email')
    ordering = ('created_on') # for reverse ordering = ('-created_on')
```

If an ordering attribute is set on the view, this will be used as the default ordering.

Typically you'd instead control this by setting `order_by` on the initial queryset, but using the ordering parameter on the view allows you to specify the ordering in a way that it can then be passed automatically as context to a rendered template

Comment: thanks
ordering_fields = ('"poduct__id")
and send orderby:product__id

Comment: @AndrewMedvedsky glad to help.Please accept the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 5):

You can try specifying `product__id` to perform ordering based on the `id` of `product`.

```
orderby = product__id
```

Specify `ordering_fields` in your viewset.

```
ordering_fields = ('product__id', )
```

Comment: Did you specify ordering fields as `product__id`?